# Call to a member function setLock() on a non-object app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Lock.php on line 162

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I'm getting the following error on my Magento 1.9.1 website:

```
Call to a member function setLock() on a non-object app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Lock.php on line 162
```

Below is lines 160 - 167 of the lock.php file.

```
  protected function _setLockDb($lockName, $block = false)
    {
        if ($this->_getLockStorage()->setLock($lockName)) {
            self::$_lockDb[$lockName] = $lockName;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Try clearing your cache and reindexing

Comment: I tried this but when I try to reindex I get the same error